# Combining Asp.Net Core server-side and React client-side

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, npm, asp.net-core

I have created simple Asp.Net default project in Visual Studio 2015 with template: *ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core) / Web Application, No Authentification*.

Then, I created **package.json**, to load all stufs for React, here it is:

```
  {
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "name": "asp.net",
    "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "6.18.0",
    "webpack": "1.14.0",
    "babel-core": "6.21.0",
    "babel-loader": "6.2.10",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.18.0",
    "react": "15.4.1",
    "react-dom": "15.4.1" 
  }
}
```

My **webpack-config.js**:

```
var config = {
    entry: './ClientApp/main.jsx',

    output: {
        path: './wwwroot/js',
        filename: 'index.js',
    },

    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        port: 8080
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
           {
               test: /\.jsx?$/,
               exclude: /node_modules/,
               loader: 'babel',

               query: {
                   presets: ['es2015', 'react']
               }
           }
        ]
    }
}

module.exports = config;
```

It works fine, however, the main problem, that we need to run independently Kestrel for server-side and npm for client-side.

How can I start all client-side (npm's) scripts to create *index.js* file, when I'm starting my project from Visual Studio?

Comment: You can add [WebPack Task Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebPackTaskRunner) to Visual Studio and have it run your things, even watching in the background

Answer (score 0):

In Startup.cs file in Configure method set this:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            ...
            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "client";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer("start");
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried this yourself?